# Process executes functions, but they are not doing their job

Tags: python, process, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm doing project on RPi and came across problem, that I can't solve. I'm using multiprocess to calculate wind speed with anemometer, and servo based platform to move around pv panel. In the main function I declare processes and objects:

```
def main():
    ane = Anemometer(pin=38, radius=65, anamometer_factor=1, action_time=5, 
                     measurment_fraquency=0.01, max_wind_speed=40, mesurment_time=30)
    prb = PhotoresistorBase(TR=1, TL=3, BR=0, BL=2, signifficant_diff=40)
    BS = Servo(pin=12, min_val=10, max_val=50)
    US = Servo(pin=18, min_val=29, max_val=43)
    pv_based = Pv(6)
    pv_servo = Pv(5)
    
    ...

    calculate_wind_vel_p = Process(target=calculate_wind_vel, args=(ane, BS, US))
    calculate_power_p = Process(target=calculate_power, args=(pv_based, pv_servo))
    turn_platform_p = Process(target=turn_platform, args=(prb, BS, US))

    calculate_wind_vel_p.start()
    calculate_power_p.start()
    turn_platform_p.start()

    calculate_wind_vel_p.join()
    calculate_power_p.join()
    turn_platform_p.join()
```

Process calculate_power_p works great, problem appears in two other processes

Process calculate_wind_vel_p targets function calculate_wind_vel, which looks like this:

```
def calculate_wind_vel(ane, BS, US):
    while True:
        wind_speed = ane.calculate_mean_wind_velocity()
        ...
        data = (datetime.datetime.now(), wind_speed)
        insert_vel_data(conn, data)
        time.sleep(1)
```

and Anemometer class, which  contains calculate_mean_wind_velocity() looks like this:

```
class Anemometer:
    def __init__(self, pin, radius, anamometer_factor, action_time, 
                 measurment_fraquency, max_wind_speed, mesurment_time):
        ...
        
    
    def calculate_wind_velocity(self) -> float:
        rotations = 0
        count = 0
        endtime = time.time() + self.action_time
        sensorstart = GPIO.input(self.pin)
        circumference = (self.radius * 2 / 1000) * math.pi
        
        while time.time() < endtime:
            if GPIO.event_detected(self.pin):
                count = count + 1
                **print(count)**
                    
        if rotations==1 and sensorstart==1:
            rotations = 0
    
        rots_per_second = float(count/3/self.action_time)
        wind_vel = float((rots_per_second)*circumference*self.anamometer_factor)
        
        **print("Wind vel: " + str(wind_vel))**
    
        return wind_vel
    
    def calculate_mean_wind_velocity(self) -> float:
        sum = 0
        measure_count = int(self.mesurment_time/self.action_time)
        
        for _ in range(measure_count):
            sum += self.calculate_wind_velocity()
        
        return float(sum/measure_count)
```

**The Problem:**

When process executes calculate_wind_vel() it jumps to ane.calculate_mean_wind_velocity(). The second function, executes calculate_wind_velocity e.g 4 times and calculate mean wind speed.
When calculate_wind_velocity() starts, program prints 'count' only once (first bolded print) and later count **does not increment** despite event is triggered. Than it calculate wind speed, with that one counted interruption. Later when calculate_wind_velocity() is execute again (**process target has while True:**) count is not incremented at all!

weirdest thing is that, when I run this code without process, just paste this into main():

```
ane = Anemometer(pin=38, radius=65, anamometer_factor=1, action_time=5, 
                  measurment_fraquency=0.01, max_wind_speed=40, mesurment_time=30)
while True:
    ret = ane.calculate_mean_wind_velocity()
    print(ret)
    time.sleep(2)
```

It works perfect - it calculates every single *GPIO.event_detected(self.pin)* and wind_speed, so **it has smth to do with processes!**.

Similar problem with moving platform - process executes functions from servo class, but it does not move, functions don't calculate/change state.

Comment: The event might not be firing because multiprocessing does not share it's state between processes. If you pass an object to a child process, and (for unix) attempt to modify it from within the child, then a duplicate will be created which will not reflect changes made to the original object in parent process

Comment: It is very dicey initializing a hardware device in one Process and then trying to use it in another Process.  Unless your device manual specifically says that this will work, which I highly doubt, I wouldn't expect it to be possible.  That the code runs when you move it into a single-process program is a clue that this is your problem.  Different Processes are almost the same as different computers.  I see that you actually use each device in a separate Process.  Why not initialize them in the Process functions instead of in main?

Comment: Yeah, initializing in process works great! I'm new to multiprocessing, i didn't figure it out. Thanks for advice!